# How to get data into proper numpy dimension format?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, neural-network, deep-learning

I am trying to train a neural network for image classification.  I am having trouble getting my data into a proper numpy array format.  To feed into the network, my array must be of dimension (9068,184,184,1).  The problem is if I check the length of the array, it just returns (9068,).  If I check the length of an individual element in the array, it returns (184,184,1).  How can I make it so that the whole array's length will be four dimensional (9068,184,184,1) so my neural network can take it as input?

Below is my code.  I have a (9068,2) dataframe with the file names.  I am grabbing the file name, reading it in to an array as pixel information, and storing it into another array.

```
path = '/home/vivek/Downloads/kaggle_ndsb2-master/data_segmenter_trainset/'

for ii in pairing_table['image']:    
    new_path = os.path.join(path,ii)
    img = Image.open(new_path)
    print type(ii)

for ii in range(0,len(image_table['image'])):
    new_path = os.path.join(path,image_table['image'][ii])
    img = Image.open(new_path)
    img2 = np.array(img.getdata()).reshape(184, 184, -1)
    #print(type(img))
    image_table['image'][ii] = img2
    img.close()


for ii in range(0,len(image_table['mask'])):
    new_path = os.path.join(path,image_table['mask'][ii])
    img = Image.open(new_path)
    img2 = np.array(img.getdata()).reshape(184, 184, -1)
    image_table['mask'][ii] = img2
    img.close()

print(image_table['image'][0].shape)  #this is returning (184,184,1)
print(image_table['image'].shape)   #this is returning (9068,)   should be (9068,184,184,1)
print(image_table['mask'][0].shape)  #this is returning (184,184,1)
print(image_table['mask'].shape)   #this is returning (9068,)   should be (9068,184,184,1)
```

Comment: You mean if you check the `shape`, not the length. If your array `x` has shape `(n,)`, but `item = x[0]` has shape `(a,b,c)`, then you may have a situation like the following: `x = array([[array(item1),array(item2),..]])`, instead of `x=array([item1,item2,...])`

Comment: Can you see if `image_table['image'][:10]` is like this? If it is a numpy array and `array` appears in `print(image_table['image'][:10]` more than once, it is not being generated correctly

Comment: It would helpful if you could provide a testable code, see [mcve], you could for example replace the `Image.open` lines by using `np.ones((nx, ny))`

Comment: @kevinkayaks  I believe you are right.                                                                          I did the following:                                                                                                                                `print(image_table['image'][:10]) #returns the first 10 arrays of images print(image_table['image'][:10].shape)) # (10,) print(type(image_table['image'][0])) #class 'numpy.ndarray' print(image_table['image'][0].shape) #184,184,1 `                                                         Would you happen to know how I could fix this?